# listings package doesn't render brackets correctly

Tags: listings, code

I'm trying to list some code using the listings package, however if use ttfamily font, brackets don't render correctly.
This is what it looks like[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your screenshot ...

Comment: If you're using `pdflatex` try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Thanks @daleif, that fixed it!

Comment: @user5753059 I've added it as an answer

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. You must have some strange setting. Please, add a minimal example of code that produces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of please always post a full minimal example others can copy and test as is.

It is a known fact that `<>` used in text gives ¡ and ¿ if running under `pdflatex` and **without** `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as the default font encoding `OT1` performs many loops.

Thus for `pdflatex` the solution is to add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Sorry about that, however I tried looking for this specific issue but nothing came up (perhaps I wasn't searching with the right words)